# How do i get the object from one sub to the other sub

Tags: vb.net

What i am trying to do is to get the intGuestID1 from page_load to be used in bth_add area
Because i am trying to get the ID when it has been clicked from another form to frmAddFollowUp so i tried to request it from the page_load as when i request from the add button, it only gives me the number 0 instead of the id from the previous form.

```
Partial Class frmAddFollowUp
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles   Me.Load

    Dim objCDBFeedback As New CDBFeedback
    Dim objCDBDepartment As New CDBDepartment

    Dim intGuestID1 As Integer
    Dim arrList As New ArrayList





    If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
        intGuestID1 = Request.QueryString("id")

        arrList = objCDBDepartment.getAllDepartmentDropDownList
        lstDepartment.DataSource = arrList
        lstDepartment.DataTextField = "DepartmentName"
        lstDepartment.DataValueField = "Department"
        lstDepartment.DataBind()



    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim CheckBoolean As Boolean = True
    Dim objCDBFeedback As New CDBFeedback
    Dim objCFeedback As New CFeedback

    If txtStaffName.Text = "" Then
        lblValidateStaffName.Text = "*Please enter Staff Name."
        CheckBoolean = False
    Else

        lblValidateStaffName.Text = ""
    End If

    If txtFollowUpSummary.Text = "" Then
        lblValidateFollowUpSummary.Text = "*Please enter Follow up summary."
        CheckBoolean = False
    ElseIf txtFollowUpSummary.Text.Contains("'") Then
        txtFollowUpSummary.Text = txtFollowUpSummary.Text.Replace("'", "''")
    Else
        lblValidateFollowUpSummary.Text = ""
    End If

    If txtAmount2.Text = "" Then
        lblValidateAmount2.Text = "*Please enter the Amount or put in NIL if there is no amount."
        CheckBoolean = False
    Else
        lblValidateAmount2.Text = ""
    End If

    If CheckBoolean = False Then

        If txtStaffName.Text.Contains("''") Then
            txtStaffName.Text = txtStaffName.Text.Replace("''", "'")
        End If
        If txtFollowUpSummary.Text.Contains("''") Then
            txtFollowUpSummary.Text = txtFollowUpSummary.Text.Replace("''", "'")
        End If

    Else
        Dim intNumOfRecordsAffected As Integer
        objCFeedback.GuestId = intGuestID1
        objCFeedback.Feedback = txtFollowUpSummary.Text
        objCFeedback.Department = lstDepartment.SelectedItem.Value
        objCFeedback.StaffName = txtStaffName.Text

        objCFeedback.Amount = txtAmount2.Text

        intNumOfRecordsAffected = objCDBFeedback.addNewFollowUp(objCFeedback)
        Response.Redirect("frmIncident.aspx")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may either specify `ByRef` parameter type or use `Function` that returns reference of an object. In your code-snippet, you may declare variable at class-level (fields) so you may use them in different event handlers/sub.

Answer (score 0):

Make intGuestID1 a private member variable. That will allow you to access this variable in both functions.

Is this code compiling? I do not see intGuestID1 being declared in btnAdd_Click, this should be throwing an error.

To declare a private member variable add the following above the Page_Load function, for example:

```
Partial Class frmAddFollowUp 
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page 

Private _intGuestID1 as Integer ' The _ prefix is just a naming convention that is used for class member variables, if you don't like it, you can remove it. 

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles   Me.Load
```

Now, in your Page_Load method, remove the line   Dim intGuestID1 As Integer, as you no longer need to declare this. Finally, anywhere you see intGuestID1, rename it to _intGuestID1

Also, some ways to possibly refactor this is to create a Read Only Property that encapsulates the fact that you're getting _intGuestID1 from the QueryString. See the following example:

```
Private ReadOnly Property GuestID1() as Int32
Get
   Return Request.QueryString("id") 
End Get
End Property
```

One of the benefits of doing this is to perform any checks on the value before using it, such as, is it an actual number that is stored in Request.QueryString("id"), or is the user allowed to have access to the entity represented by this id, or whatever else you can think of.  When you do this, you'll need to change all references to _intGuestID1 to GuestID1.

Comment: How do i make it a private member variable? Sorry for being new in this.. as for intGuestID1 not being declared in btnAdd_click.. because i was thinking whether i could just declare it in page_load and take it in to btnAdd_click but i do not know the code to take it in

Comment: No need to be sorry, we all start somewhere. Give me a sec, I will update my answer on how to do this